# How to rename and modify ethernet interface in Android during runtime?

Tags: networking, 9.0-pie, ethernet

I have an Android emulator based on Android Pie running in a Docker container. Docker by default assigns `eth0` interface, we use the `eth0` IP assigned by Docker and write it to `ipconfig.txt` (`/data/misc/ethernet/ipconfig.txt`) to let Android use an ethernet tracker to track the `eth0` interface, which happens during the boot up phase.

We want to create a new ethernet interface for certain apps to enable some sort of tunneling. As part of that, we are trying to rename existing `eth0` to `eth1` and create GRE-enabled `eth0`. In terms of IP link, I tried the following commands after the emulator completed the boot-up:

```
ip link set eth0 down && ip link set eth0 name eth1 && ip link set eth1 up
ip link add eth0 type gretap remote 10.0.0.1 local $ETH1_IP dev eth1
ip addr add 172.18.0.2/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1368
```

After doing the above renaming, the emulator doesn't have network connectivity, unless we specifically specify the interface name like `ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8`.

My understanding is whenever we make any changes to the ethernet interface using `ip link` commands, Android listens to NETLINK and processes these updates, so we don't need to do anything extra for this to work.